# Retaining CA cert on rebuilding kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kops

Everytime a kuberneters cluster is built, it generates a new CA. is there a way to specify a CA cert file to use? like pfx with kops?

Comment: You have failed to specify _what_ is building your cluster, which is doubly weird given that you specified that you know how to do that task using kops

Comment: no i don't know how to do it using kops. Hence the question

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. But you might have to use your own custom script to build the k8s cluster.
Follow kubernetes the hard way  as reference to develop cluster setup scripts

https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way